# Map My Documents Folder to New Location in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, my-documents

How can I map the location of the My Documents folder on Windows 7 to a new location?  My system has a 60GB SSD as the primary/boot drive and a 160GB HDD.  I would like the My Documents folder to be on the HDD, not the SSD.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googled around, found these you could try:

- http://headstrongfarm.hubpages.com/hub/Windows-7_-_Moving_My_Documents
- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18629-user-folders-change-default-location.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the official Microsoft help article:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/redirect-folder-new-location#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 1):

You want to use folder redirection to change the Documents shell pointer to the new HDD path:

1. Jump directly to your user profile folder using **Start + R,** then type **`C:\Users\Profilename`** where *Profilename* is usually the same as your Windows username
2. Right click on the My Documents folder > **Properties**
3. On the Location tab, click the **Move** button
4. Browse to the desired path on D: and click **Select Folder** to save.  If needed, you can create a new folder in the *Select a Destination* dialog by right clicking in the right pane > New > Folder
5. Back in Documents Properties, click **OK** to save your change and **Yes** to confirm you want all the content relocated to the new path